# drivers questin

Tags: 12.04, drivers, graphics

I use a HDD with ubuntu 12.04 on it for school, and when i do school related work I plug it on my PC and work on it, but I've found some problems and i think its due to the graphics drivers, I installed the nvidia ones for my PC, but the school PC has integrated graphic chipset, so i would need different drivers. Can I install both on the same ubuntu system without causing driver conflicts or something?

Comment: Having both drivers should be fine - most integrated graphics drivers shouldn't conflict with nvidia drivers.

Comment: I have done this about four times and each time the only issue I had was graphics drivers, I found if I uninstalled the driver before attaching it to the new computer then I had no trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can install multiple drivers. When Ubuntu boots, it looks for what hardware works, then chooses matching drivers. Even if `lspci | grep "Display\VGA"` shows a non-Nvidia integrated graphics controller, you can add the non-nVidia driver.